# kubernetes-dashboard cannot display metrics of metrics-server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I built a cluster of kubernetes and installed kubernetes-dashboard and metrics-server, but metric information for the metrics-server (CPU and memory) is not displayed on kubernetes-dashboard.

I installed kubernetes-dashboard using `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`.
I installed metrics-server using `git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git` and using `kubectl apply -f 1.8+/`.

I modified the configuration of the deploy/1.8+/metrics-server-deployment.yaml file.

```
containers:
      - name: metrics-server
        image: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coupe of things here.
Since you are deploying `v1.10.1` of Dashboard you have to have Kubernetes 1.10 or older (described in [release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases/tag/v1.10.1)), and Heapster deployed in your cluster (described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#create-an-authentication-token-rbac)):

> Heapster has to be running in the cluster for the metrics and graphs to be available. Read more about it in Integrations guide.

`metrics-server` deployment needs to have **`args:`** instead of `command:` in the deployment, as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/#deployment).
Like so:

```
    containers:
          - name: metrics-server
            image: registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.3
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            args:
            - /metrics-server
            - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
            - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

---

If you are using Kubernetes newer than 1.10 you can go with Dashboard v2.0.0-beta1 for k8s 1.14, or v2.0.0-beta2 for k8s 1.15. Then you don`t need Heapster, since the betas added support for gathering metrics from metrics-server directly. More details in [release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases).

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand